# React Native - EAS submit IOS app Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, mobile, expo

My issue: I am using eas to build and submit IOS to the apple store, everything is fine until I upload the build to the apple store, I get an email like this: ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

This is my config on eas.json file:

```
"production": {
  "distribution": "store",
  "ios": {
    "image": "latest"
  }
}
```

**Is there a way to import the SwiftSupport folder manually or can it be configurable in eas.json? please help me.**